# How can I force the iPhone X to display my app with black bars?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone-x

I want to force my Swift iOS app to display in "compatibility mode" on the iPhone X (I'm aware of the new guidelines). How can I do this while still using the iOS 11 SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that Apple will likely reject such an app since they announced that all new apps (and soon updates) must support the iPhone X, a solution is to use launch images instead of a launch screen storyboard. Then simply not supply an iPhone X launch image.

Or, ignoring your iOS 11 SDK requirement, use a launch screen storyboard but build your app with Xcode 8 and a Base SDK of iOS 10.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty easy to do actually:

In `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` do the following:

```
let screenFrame = UIScreen.main.bounds
window.frame = screenFrame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 100)
```

I'm pretty sure, however that Apple will not approve doing so :D (I assume you know what you're doing since you explicitly stated you're aware of the new guidelines).